# How do I fuzz a nil value in Go 1.18?

Tags: go, pointers, null, fuzzing

I am trying to use Go 1.18 `go test -fuzz` command to fuzz nil values so that I can ensure I didn't forget safety checks before attempting to dereference a pointer to a string.

Here is my attempt:

```golang
// main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func HandleString(s *string) {
    // most common programmer error is dereferencing nil pointers without safety checks
    fmt.Println(*s)
}

func main() {
    s := "Hello, world"
    HandleString(&s)
}
```

```golang
// main_test.go
package main

import "testing"

func FuzzHandleString(f *testing.F) {
    h := "hello world"
    for _, seed := range []*string{nil, new(string), &h} {
        f.Add(seed)
    }
    f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, in *string) {
        HandleString(in)
    })
}
```

Unfortunately i get an error saying go fuzz doesn't support pointers and only supports the string datatype.

I found a workaround by writing my test like this:

```golang
package main

import "testing"

func FuzzHandleString(f *testing.F) {
    h := "hello world"
    for _, seed := range []string{"-1", "", h} {
        f.Add(seed)
    }
    f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, in string) {
        if in == "-1" {
            HandleString(nil)
        } else {
            HandleString(&in)
        }
    })
}
```

This is a horrible design, and makes the seed data array not easily reusable , and requires logic in every fuzz function to trick my method into taking a nil value.

Surely there has to be a better way I didn't think of?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a valid use of fuzz? The point of fuzzing is to test random values. What you're doing is testing bounds and how invalid values are handled, these should be explicit tests. And shouldn't passing `nil` into a string handling function be an error?

Comment: Fuzzzing doesn't replace / substitute "good old tests", it complements it.

Comment: to test `nil` use unit tests. Fuzzing is for variable input.

Comment: Also, to add to this, your function definition seems a bit awkward.
The way golang handles string keyword is by using a pointer to whatever holds the actual text value.
So, IMHO the right way to handle would actually be to fix the function definition itself.
i.e `handleString(s string)` and therefore the possibility of s being nil is now mostly impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is awkward because this is not what [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing) is for. Fuzzing is to throw random values at your functions to test edge cases you may not have thought about.

What you're doing is more like bounds testing. You have a known tricky inputs like `nil`, or empty string, or an empty array. Test them in their own unit tests.

Finally, I'd question why `nil` is a valid input to `handleString`. `nil` is not a string. It should be an error, unless there's a good reason otherwise, and you should be testing for that error.

Comment: Fuzzing or fuzz testing is an automated software testing technique that involves providing **invalid**, **unexpected**, or **random data** as inputs to a computer program.
The program is then monitored for exceptions such as crashes, failing built-in code assertions, or potential memory leaks.
- Wikipedia

Comment: Isn't a null pointer exception a common way to crash a program? If the purpose of fuzzing is to detect errors before they happen, including nil seems like an absolutely essential when testing against unexpected input.

Comment: @Ben Yes, you should test for a null pointer, but that's a whole different class of input. Fuzz testing is useful, for example, to throw random strings at a parser, or random numbers at a math function. The purpose of fuzzing is to generate test input beyond what a human tester can think to try.